What comments did Doyakonga make about Minase Inorin's colleagues?
The already-deleted Twitter account Doyakonga posted many twits commenting on Minase Inorin's colleagues. What are those comments? Please be as comprehensive as possible.

The Anime Hunch article I linked to in my answer to your other question lists a few of them but is presumably not comprehensive, so I won't repeat it as an answer here.
